# Connection Error When Setting Up a Subscription for SQL Server (Transactional) Replication

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, ssms, replication, transactional-replication

I am encountering a connection to the target database error while setting up a Subscription for SQL Server (Transactional) Replication in SSMS.

I can connect to the target server database from the local SSMS using local SQL Server authentication. Additionally, I was able to connect to the target server (dev database) when setting up a replication subscription from a dev database. However, I am facing this error while setting up a replication subscription from the prod database to a prod database on the same server.

[Connection error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4x2n.png)

Do you have any ideas on how to resolve it?